# Plotting datetimeindex on x-axis with matplotlib creates wrong ticks in pandas 0.15 in contrast to 0.14

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I create a simple pandas dataframe with some random values and a DatetimeIndex like so:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import randint
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create a random dataframe with datetimeindex
dateRange = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', '3/30/2011', freq='D')
randomInts = randint(1, 50, len(dateRange))
df = pd.DataFrame({'RandomValues' : randomInts}, index=dateRange)
```

Then I plot it in two different ways:

```
# plot with pandas own matplotlib wrapper
df.plot()

# plot directly with matplotlib pyplot
plt.plot(df.index, df.RandomValues)

plt.show()
```

(Do not use both statements at the same time as they plot on the same figure.)

I use **Python 3.4 64bit** and **matplotlib 1.4**. With **pandas 0.14**, both statements give me the expected plot (they use slightly different formatting of the x-axis which is okay; note that data is random so the plots do not look the same):
[image: pandas 0.14: pandas plot]

[image: pandas 0.14: matplotlib plot]

However, when using **pandas 0.15**, the pandas plot looks alright but the matplotlib plot has some strange tick format on the x-axis:

[image: pandas 0.15: pandas plot]

[image: pandas 0.15: matplotlib plot]

Is there any good reason for this behaviour and why it has changed from pandas 0.14 to 0.15?

Comment: A workaround is to call `to_pydatetimes`: ``plt.plot(df.index.to_pydatetimes(), df.RandomValues)``.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Note that this bug was fixed in pandas 0.15.1 (https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/8693), and `plt.plot(df.index, df.RandomValues)` now just works again.

---

The reason for this change in behaviour is that starting from 0.15, the pandas `Index` object is no longer a numpy ndarray subclass. But the *real reason* is that matplotlib does not support the `datetime64` dtype.

As a workaround, in the case you want to use the matplotlib `plot` function, you can convert the index to python datetime's using `to_pydatetime`:

```
plt.plot(df.index.to_pydatetime(), df.RandomValues)
```

---

More in detail explanation:

Because `Index` is no longer a ndarray subclass, matplotlib will convert the index to a numpy array with `datetime64` dtype (while before, it retained the `Index` object, of which scalars are returned as `Timestamp` values, a subclass of `datetime.datetime`, which matplotlib can handle). In the `plot` function, it calls `np.atleast_1d()` on the input which now returns a datetime64 array, which matplotlib handles as integers.

I opened an issue about this (as this gets possibly a lot of use): https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8614

Comment: Thanks for your effort opening an issue for this! The workaround is fine, letting me use pandas 0.15 without having to change too much :)

Comment: I'm facing the same issue with matplotlib 2.1.0 and pandas 0.21.0. The workaround with `to_pydatetime` still works.

Comment: Yes, that will be fixed in the upcoming 0.21.1 release (see http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#restore-matplotlib-datetime-converter-registration)

Answer (score 3):

With matplotlib 1.5.0 this 'just works':

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import randint
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create a random dataframe with datetimeindex
dateRange = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', '3/30/2011', freq='D')
randomInts = randint(1, 50, len(dateRange))
df = pd.DataFrame({'RandomValues' : randomInts}, index=dateRange)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot('RandomValues', data=df)
```

[image: demo image]

Answer (score 0):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 5))
plt.plot(one_label.index.strftime('%Y-%m'),one_label, label='label')
plt.plot(one_pred.index.strftime('%Y-%m'),one_pred.values, label='pred')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The date can be displayed normally by using .strftime()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).