# Why do I get "python int too large to convert to C long" errors when I use matplotlib's DateFormatter to format dates on the x axis?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pandas

Following [this answer's use of DateFormatter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5502162/2766558), I tried to plot a time series and label its x axis with years using pandas 0.15.0 and matplotlib 1.4.2:

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas.io.data as pdio
import scipy as sp

t1 = dt.datetime(1960, 1, 1)
t2 = dt.datetime(2014, 6, 1)
data = pdio.DataReader("GS10", "fred", t1, t2).resample("Q", how=sp.mean)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(data.index, data.GS10)
ax1.set_xlabel("Year")
ax1.set_ylabel("Rate (%)")
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.dates.DateFormatter("%Y"))
fig.suptitle("10-yr Treasury Rate", fontsize=14)

fig.savefig('test.eps')
```

The final line throws an error: `OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long`
 with this traceback:

> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py:239:
>   FormatterWarning: Exception in image/png formatter: Python int too
>   large to convert to C long   FormatterWarning,
>    Traceback (most recent call
>   last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('D:/username/latex_template/new_pandas_example.py', wdir='D:/username/latex_template')
>
> File
>   "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 580, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 48, in execfile
>       exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "D:/username/latex_template/new_pandas_example.py", line 18, in
>   
>       fig.savefig('test.eps')
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line
>   1470, in savefig
>       self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py",
>   line 2194, in print_figure
>       **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_ps.py",
>   line 992, in print_eps
>       return self._print_ps(outfile, 'eps', *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_ps.py",
>   line 1020, in _print_ps
>       **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_ps.py",
>   line 1110, in _print_figure
>       self.figure.draw(renderer)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 59,
>   in draw_wrapper
>       draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line
>   1079, in draw
>       func(*args)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 59,
>   in draw_wrapper
>       draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_base.py", line
>   2092, in draw
>       a.draw(renderer)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 59,
>   in draw_wrapper
>       draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1114,
>   in draw
>       ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks(renderer)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 957,
>   in _update_ticks
>       tick_tups = [t for t in self.iter_ticks()]
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 957,
>   in 
>       tick_tups = [t for t in self.iter_ticks()]
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 905,
>   in iter_ticks
>       for i, val in enumerate(majorLocs)]
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 905,
>   in 
>       for i, val in enumerate(majorLocs)]
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line 411,
>   in **call**
>       dt = num2date(x, self.tz)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line 345,
>   in num2date
>       return _from_ordinalf(x, tz)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line 225,
>   in _from_ordinalf
>       dt = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(ix)
>
> OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

Am I using `DateFormatter` incorrectly here? How can I easily put years (or any time format, since my time series might differ) on the a-axis of a matplotlib figure?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a 'regression' in pandas 0.15 (due to the refactor of Index), see https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3727 and https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8614, but **is fixed in 0.15.1**.

---

Short story: matplotlib now sees the pandas index as an array of `datetime64[ns]` values (which are actually very large int64s), instead of an array of Timestamps (which are subclass of datetime.datetime, and can be handled by matplotlib) in previous versions of pandas. So the underlying reason is that matplotlib does not handle datetime64 as date values but as ints.

For pandas 0.15.0 (but better upgrade to a newer version), there are two possible **workarounds**:

- Register the `datetime64` type, so it will also be handled as a date by matplotlib:

  ```
  units.registry[np.datetime64] = pd.tseries.converter.DatetimeConverter()
  ```
- Or convert the DatetimeIndex (with datetime64 values) to an array of `datetime.datetime` values with the `to_pydatetime` method, and plot this:

  ```
  ax1.plot(data.index.to_pydatetime(), data.GS10)
  ```

---

related question: [Plotting datetimeindex on x-axis with matplotlib creates wrong ticks in pandas 0.15 in contrast to 0.14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26526230/plotting-datetimeindex-on-x-axis-with-matplotlib-creates-wrong-ticks-in-pandas-0/26529774#26529774)

Comment: Thanks for the answer; you were correct in that this was fixed in pandas 0.15.1. I just updated this morning and my original code sample works exactly as intended. (Maybe edit your question to include that?)

Comment: Yes, that will be fixed in the upcoming 0.21.1 release (see http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#restore-matplotlib-datetime-converter-registration)