# Python matplotlib.dates.date2num: converting numpy array to matplotlib datetimes

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a custom chart with datetime axis. My understanding is that matplotlib requires a float format which is days since epoch. So, I want to convert a numpy array to the float epoch as required by matplotlib.

The datetime values are stored in a numpy array called t:

```
In [235]: t
Out[235]: array(['2008-12-01T00:00:59.000000000-0800',
                 '2008-12-01T00:00:59.000000000-0800',
                 '2008-12-01T00:00:59.000000000-0800',
                 '2008-12-01T00:09:26.000000000-0800',
                 '2008-12-01T00:09:41.000000000-0800'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

Apparently, matplotlib.dates.date2num only accepts a sequence of python datetimes as input (not numpy datetimes arrays):

```
import matplotlib.dates as dates
plt_dates = dates.date2num(t)
```

raises AttributeError: 'numpy.datetime64' object has no attribute 'toordinal'

How should I resolve this issue? I hope to have a solution that works for all types of numpy.datetime like object.

My best workaround (which I am not sure to be correct) is not to use date2num at all. Instead, I try to use the following:

```
z = np.array([0]).astype(t.dtype)
plt_dates = (t - z)/ np.timedelta64(1,'D')
```

Even, if this solution is correct, it is nicer to use library functions, instead of manual adhoc workarounds.

Comment: The problem is because `numpy` has the type `datetime64`, whereas the `matplotlib` library is expecting the type `datetime`.  This makes the question a close-to-duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703720/converting-between-datetime-timestamp-and-datetime64).  Your workaround should work and is very similar to the accepted answer there.

Comment: Importing `pandas` may make the datetime64 axes 'just work'.

Comment: @JRichardSnape: Not sure :S! In my case this seems to happen to plot_date(df.index,....) that worked before upgrading anaconda, plus using plot_date(df.index.values.astype(datetime.datetime),...  does not work either :S... (conversion works, plotting breaks...)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For a quick fix, use:

```
import matplotlib.dates as dates
plt_dates = dates.date2num(t.to_pydatetime())
```

or:

```
import matplotlib.dates as dates
plt_dates = dates.date2num(list(t))
```

It seems the latest (matplotlib.__version__ '2.1.0') does not like numpy arrays... *Edit:* In my case, after checking the source code, the problem seems to be that the latest matplotlib.cbook cannot create an iterable from the numpy array and thinks the array is a number.

For similar but a bit more complex problems, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703720/converting-between-datetime-timestamp-and-datetime64, possibly [Why do I get "python int too large to convert to C long" errors when I use matplotlib's DateFormatter to format dates on the x axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642133/why-do-i-get-python-int-too-large-to-convert-to-c-long-errors-when-i-use-matpl), and maybe  [matplotlib plot_date AttributeError: 'numpy.datetime64' object has no attribute 'toordinal'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47465941/matplotlib-plot-date-attributeerror-numpy-datetime64-object-has-no-attribute) (if someone answers)
Edit: someone answered, his code using to_pydatetime() seems best, also: [pandas 0.21.0 Timestamp compatibility issue with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47404653/pandas-0-21-0-timestamp-compatibility-issue-with-matplotlib), though that did not work in my case (because of python 2???)