# How to convert list of `numpy.datetime64` to `matplotlib.dates`?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Here is my simple object:

```
[numpy.datetime64('2017-01-03T00:00:00.000000000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2017-01-04T00:00:00.000000000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2017-01-05T00:00:00.000000000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2017-01-06T00:00:00.000000000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2017-01-09T00:00:00.000000000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2017-01-10T00:00:00.000000000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2017-01-11T00:00:00.000000000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2017-01-12T00:00:00.000000000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2017-01-13T00:00:00.000000000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2017-01-16T00:00:00.000000000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2017-01-17T00:00:00.000000000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2017-01-18T00:00:00.000000000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2017-01-19T00:00:00.000000000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2017-01-20T00:00:00.000000000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2017-01-23T00:00:00.000000000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2017-01-24T00:00:00.000000000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2017-01-25T00:00:00.000000000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2017-01-26T00:00:00.000000000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2017-01-27T00:00:00.000000000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2017-02-01T00:00:00.000000000')]
```

instead of using a loop an empty list convert one by one, is there any shortcuts for that? Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, list comprehensions / generator expressions? But they still process items one by one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34843513/python-matplotlib-dates-date2num-converting-numpy-array-to-matplotlib-datetimes Does this help?

Comment: map a function??

Answer (score 4):

My favourite solution here would be one that seems a bit hidden in this thread:
[Converting between datetime, Timestamp and datetime64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703720/converting-between-datetime-timestamp-and-datetime64), which is to use `tolist()`. Because `tolist()` returns different types, depending on the array type, a conversion to `ms` is needed to get `datetime` objects. `datetime` objects can be directly plotted with matplotlib, or one can apply `matplotlib.dates.date2num()` on them.

So if `a` is the numpy array as above,

```
x = a.astype("M8[ms]").tolist()
```

results in a list of datetime objects.

Complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

a = np.array([np.datetime64('2017-01-03T00:00:00.000000000'),
     np.datetime64('2017-01-04T00:00:00.000000000'),
     np.datetime64('2017-01-05T00:00:00.000000000'),
     np.datetime64('2017-01-06T00:00:00.000000000'),
     np.datetime64('2017-01-09T00:00:00.000000000'),
     np.datetime64('2017-01-10T00:00:00.000000000'),
     np.datetime64('2017-01-11T00:00:00.000000000'),
     np.datetime64('2017-01-12T00:00:00.000000000'),
     np.datetime64('2017-01-13T00:00:00.000000000'),
     np.datetime64('2017-01-16T00:00:00.000000000'),
     np.datetime64('2017-01-17T00:00:00.000000000'),
     np.datetime64('2017-01-18T00:00:00.000000000'),
     np.datetime64('2017-01-19T00:00:00.000000000'),
     np.datetime64('2017-01-20T00:00:00.000000000'),
     np.datetime64('2017-01-23T00:00:00.000000000'),
     np.datetime64('2017-01-24T00:00:00.000000000'),
     np.datetime64('2017-01-25T00:00:00.000000000'),
     np.datetime64('2017-01-26T00:00:00.000000000'),
     np.datetime64('2017-01-27T00:00:00.000000000'),
     np.datetime64('2017-02-01T00:00:00.000000000')])

x = a.astype("M8[ms]").tolist()
y = np.random.rand(len(a))

plt.plot(x, y, color="limegreen")

plt.show()
```