# matplotlib not mapping axis correctly

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Before matplotlib used to use the index as the x-axis, which is what I want.

Now it doesn't, why is this?

```
            Close   Prediction
Date        
2017-06-21  155.03  152.586975
2017-06-22  154.89  153.450424
2017-06-23  158.02  150.374527
2017-06-26  157.50  149.241684
2017-06-27  151.03  148.880630
```

Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt2

plt2.plot(joined['Prediction'], color='red', label='Prediction')
plt2.plot(joined['Close'], color='blue', label='Actual')
plt2.legend(loc='upper left')
plt2.show()
```

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47404653/pandas-0-21-0-timestamp-compatibility-issue-with-matplotlib) and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Pandas plot:

```
joined.plot()
```

[image]

Comment: but how can i add two sets of data?

Comment: You can merge you datasets into to joined dataframe, with the columns of the joined dataframe creating additional series on the graph.