# How to make a date-based color bar based on df.idxmax series?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, colorbar, scatter

Python beginner/first poster here.

I'm running into trouble adding color bars to scatter plots. I have two types of plot: one that shows all the data color-coded by date, and one that shows just the maximum values of my data color-coded by date. In the first case, I can use the df.index (which is datetime) to make my color bar, but in the second case, I am using df2['col'].idxmax to generate the colors because my df2 is a df.groupby object which I'm using to generate the daily maximums in my data, and it does not have an accessible index.

For the first type of plot, I have succeeded in generating a date-based color bar with the code below, cobbled together from online examples:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(20,20))

smap=plt.scatter(df.col1, df.col2, s=140, 
             c=[date2num(i.date()) for i in df.index],
             marker='.')

cb = fig.colorbar(smap, orientation='vertical',
              format=DateFormatter('%d %b %y'))
```

However for the second type of plot, where I am trying to use df2['col'].idxmax to create the date series instead of df.index, the following does not work:

```
for n in cols1:
    for m in cols2:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(15,15))

        maxTimes=df2[n].idxmax()
        PlottableTimes=maxTimes.dropna() #some NaNs in the 
        #.idxmax series were giving date2num trouble

        smap2=plt.scatter(df2[n].max(), df2[m].max(),
             s=160, c=[date2num(i.date()) for i in PlottableTimes], 
             marker='.')

        cb2 = fig.colorbar(smap2, orientation='vertical',
                      format=DateFormatter('%d %b %y'))  

        plt.show()
```

The error is: 'length of rgba sequence should be either 3 or 4'

Because the error was complaining of the color argument, I separately checked the output of the color (that is, c=) arguments in the respective plotting commands, and both look similar to me, so I can't figure out why one color argument works and the other doesn't:

one that works:

[736809.0,
 736809.0,
 736809.0,
 736809.0,
 736809.0,
 736809.0,
 736809.0,
 736809.0,
 736809.0,
 736809.0,
 ...]

one that doesn't work:

[736845.0,
 736846.0,
 736847.0,
 736848.0,
 736849.0,
 736850.0,
 736851.0,
 736852.0,
 736853.0,
 736854.0,
...]

Any suggestions or explanations? I'm running python 3.5.2. Thank you in advance for helping me understand this.

**Edit 1:** I made the following example for others to explore, and in the process realized the crux of the issue is different than my first question. The code below works the way I want it to:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(169, 8)), 
            columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e','f','g','h']) #make sample data
date_rng = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/8/2018', freq='H')
df['i']=date_rng
df = df.set_index('i') #get a datetime index
df['ts']=date_rng #get a datetime column to group by

from pandas import Grouper
df2=df.groupby(Grouper(key='ts', freq='D'))

for n in ['a','b','c','d']: #now make some plots
for m in ['e','f','g','h']:
    print(m)
    print(n)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(5,5))
    maxTimes=df2[n].idxmax()
    PlottableTimes=maxTimes.dropna()

    smap=plt.scatter(df2[n].max(), df2[m].max(), s=160, 
                     c=[date2num(i.date()) for i in PlottableTimes], 
                     marker='.')
    cb = fig.colorbar(smap, orientation='vertical',
                      format=DateFormatter('%d %b %y'))  
    plt.show()
```

The only difference between my real data and this example is that my real data has many NaNs scattered throughout. So, I think what is going wrong is that the 'c=' argument isn't long enough for the plotting command to interpret it as covering the whole date range...? For example, if I manually put in the output of the c= command, I get the following code which also works:

```
for n in ['a','b','c','d']:
    for m in ['e','f','g','h']:
        print(m)
        print(n)

        fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(5,5))
        maxTimes=df2[n].idxmax()
        PlottableTimes=maxTimes.dropna()

        smap=plt.scatter(df2[n].max(), df2[m].max(), s=160, 
                     c=[736809.0, 736810.0, 736811.0, 736812.0, 736813.0, 736814.0, 736815.0, 736816.0], 
                     marker='.')
        cb = fig.colorbar(smap, orientation='vertical',
                      format=DateFormatter('%d %b %y'))  
        plt.show()
```

But, if I shorten the c= array by some amount, to emulate what is happening in my code when NaNs are being dropped from idxmax, it gives the same error I am seeing:

```
for n in ['a','b','c','d']:
    for m in ['e','f','g','h']:
        print(m)
        print(n)

        fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(5,5))
        maxTimes=df2[n].idxmax()
        PlottableTimes=maxTimes.dropna()

        smap=plt.scatter(df2[n].max(), df2[m].max(), s=160, 
                     c=[736809.0, 736810.0, 736811.0, 736812.0, 736813.0, 736814.0], 
                     marker='.')
        cb = fig.colorbar(smap, orientation='vertical',
                      format=DateFormatter('%d %b %y'))  
        plt.show()
```

So this means the real question is: how can I grab the grouper column after grouping from the groupby object, when none of the columns appear to be grab-able with df2.col? I would like to be able to grab 'ts' from the following and use it to be the color data, instead of using idxmax:

```
df2['a'].max()

ts
2018-01-01    9
2018-01-02    9
2018-01-03    9
2018-01-04    9
2018-01-05    9
2018-01-06    9
2018-01-07    9
2018-01-08    8
Freq: D, Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You would want to read [mcve] and provide one inside your question. Else, how could people find out what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, your *Grouper* call is similar to indexing on your date time column and calling[`pandas.DataFrame.resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) specifying the aggregate function:

```
df.set_index('ts').resample('D').max()
#             a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h
# ts                                
# 2018-01-01  9  9  8  9  9  9  9  9
# 2018-01-02  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9
# 2018-01-03  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9
# 2018-01-04  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9
# 2018-01-05  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9
# 2018-01-06  9  9  9  8  9  9  9  9
# 2018-01-07  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9
# 2018-01-08  2  8  6  3  1  3  2  7
```

Therefore, the return of `df2['a'].max()` is a Pandas Resampler object, very similar to a Pandas Series and hence carries the index property which you can use for color bar specification:

```
df['a'].max().index

# DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-01', '2018-01-02', '2018-01-03', '2018-01-04',
#                '2018-01-05', '2018-01-06', '2018-01-07', '2018-01-08'],
#               dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='ts', freq='D')
```

From there you can pass into `date2num` without list comprehension:

```
date2num(df2['a'].max().index)

# array([736695., 736696., 736697., 736698., 736699., 736700., 736701., 736702.])
```

Altogether, simply use above in loop without needing *maxTimes* or *PlottableTimes*:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize = (5,5))

smap = plt.scatter(df2[n].max(), df2[m].max(), s = 160, 
                   c = date2num(df2[n].max().index), 
                   marker = '.')
cb = fig.colorbar(smap, orientation = 'vertical',
                  format = DateFormatter('%d %b %y'))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and the explanation! It makes sense the way you say it, but somehow when I plug in 

date2num(df2['a'].max().index) 
I get this error: 
"AttributeError: 'numpy.datetime64' object has no attribute 'toordinal'". It happens inside the loop as well. Am I missing a step somewhere?

Comment: Do you receive that error with posted or actual data?

Comment: With the posted data, too. I am running Python 3.5.2.

Comment: Try updating your pandas and/or matplotlib version: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47404653/1422451

Comment: Thanks! I am working on trying out your solution but I'm getting stuck trying to update pandas. It might be a little while before I can get some in-person help to walk me through what the command line errors that I'm getting mean.

Comment: On Unix (Mac/Linux) use the usual [`pip install <pkg> --upgrade`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47071257/1422451). On Windows install [binary wheel versions](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pandas) and then `pip install '/path/to/pkg.whl'`.

Comment: I apologize for the delay. I was able to update my packages and this solution now works!! Thank you so much!