# matplotlib.pyplot plot_date function breaks on cftime.datetime objects

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, netcdf4

Trying to plot data using the `matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date` function with datetime objects originating from the `netCDF4.num2date` function I get the following error:

```
In [1]: from netCDF4 import num2date

In [2]: from matplotlib.pyplot import plot_date

In [3]: d=num2date((86400,2*86400),"seconds since 2000-01-01")

In [4]: gca().plot_date(d,(0,1))
...
AttributeError: 'cftime._cftime.DatetimeGregorian' object has no attribute 'toordinal'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
ConversionError
...
ConversionError: Failed to convert value(s) to axis units: array([cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2000-01-02 00:00:00),
       cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2000-01-03 00:00:00)], dtype=object)
```

The following package versions are installed:

pandas 1.0.3

matplotlib 3.2.1

netcdf4 1.5.1.2

cftime 1.1.1.2

As the same thing perfectly works on a different machine with older package versions, I assume a version issue.
Also, I've tried the solution suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47465941/matplotlib-plot-date-attributeerror-numpy-datetime64-object-has-no-attribute) and other related threads which seemed like a similar issue, but

```
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
register_matplotlib_converters()
```

didn't help neither.

Any suggestions welcome;)

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer myself, from version 1.1.0 the `num2date` function in the cftime package changed its default behaviour to return cftime datetime instances instead of python datetime instances where possible (the option argument `only_use_cftime_datetimes` is now `True` by default, instead of `False`). The plot_date function however, at least currently, doesn't handle these.
To avoid the issue, use the arguments `only_use_cftime_datetimes=False` and `only_use_python_datetime=True` or use the convenience function `num2pydate`.