# OverflowError: int too big to convert when formatting date on pandas series plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a pandas series, but I'm encountering an error when I attempt to format the x-axis date.

(A related [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642133/why-do-i-get-python-int-too-large-to-convert-to-c-long-errors-when-i-use-matpl) was identified in the comments, but it appears that it was resolved in a much older version of pandas than what I'm using.  So, it seems like this is a new problem.)

Consider a plot of the following pandas series:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {pd.Timestamp('2021-03-15 08:30:00'): -65.926651,
     pd.Timestamp('2021-03-15 08:30:05'): -42.115551,
     pd.Timestamp('2021-03-15 08:30:10'): -24.699627,
     pd.Timestamp('2021-03-15 08:30:15'): -12.010081,
     pd.Timestamp('2021-03-15 08:30:20'): -2.781321}

s = pd.Series(d)

ax = s.plot()
```

I seek to format the x-axis date on the plot using:

```
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
format_str: str = '%H:%M:%S'
format_: DateFormatter = DateFormatter(format_str)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(format_)
```

This results in the following error:

```
      Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/VirtualEnvironments/my_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_macosx.py", line 61, in _draw
    self.figure.draw(renderer)
  File "/Users/me/VirtualEnvironments/my_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 41, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/VirtualEnvironments/my_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1863, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
  File "/Users/me/VirtualEnvironments/my_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 131, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/Users/me/VirtualEnvironments/my_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 41, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/VirtualEnvironments/my_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/deprecation.py", line 411, in wrapper
    return func(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/VirtualEnvironments/my_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2747, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
  File "/Users/me/VirtualEnvironments/my_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 131, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/Users/me/VirtualEnvironments/my_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 41, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/VirtualEnvironments/my_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1164, in draw
    ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks()
  File "/Users/me/VirtualEnvironments/my_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1022, in _update_ticks
    major_labels = self.major.formatter.format_ticks(major_locs)
  File "/Users/me/VirtualEnvironments/my_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/ticker.py", line 250, in format_ticks
    return [self(value, i) for i, value in enumerate(values)]
  File "/Users/me/VirtualEnvironments/my_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/ticker.py", line 250, in <listcomp>
    return [self(value, i) for i, value in enumerate(values)]
  File "/Users/me/VirtualEnvironments/my_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py", line 605, in __call__
    return num2date(x, self.tz).strftime(self.fmt)
  File "/Users/me/VirtualEnvironments/my_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py", line 511, in num2date
    return _from_ordinalf_np_vectorized(x, tz).tolist()
  File "/Users/me/VirtualEnvironments/my_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2108, in __call__
    return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
  File "/Users/me/VirtualEnvironments/my_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2192, in _vectorize_call
    outputs = ufunc(*inputs)
  File "/Users/me/VirtualEnvironments/my_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py", line 331, in _from_ordinalf
    np.timedelta64(int(np.round(x * MUSECONDS_PER_DAY)), 'us'))
OverflowError: int too big to convert
```

Interestingly, if I add a fractional offset to the timestamps, everything works:

```
s.index += pd.DateOffset(seconds=0.5)
```

When I examine `x` in the `np.timedelta64` call, it corresponds to the number of days since the start of the unix epoch (1 Jan 1970) only if I add a fractional part to the timestamp.  If there's no fractional part, the resulting integer is huge and seems to have no obvious relationship to the number of days since 1 Jan 1970.

What's wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get "python int too large to convert to C long" errors when I use matplotlib's DateFormatter to format dates on the x axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642133/why-do-i-get-python-int-too-large-to-convert-to-c-long-errors-when-i-use-matpl)

Comment: hmm but according to that, the bug was fixed in 0.15.1 ([released Nov 2014](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew/v0.15.1.html))

Comment: @SiHa, I am using a much newer version of pandas: 1.1.5.

Comment: It's not `pandas`.  It's `matplotlib`,

Comment: the link says it's a `matplotlib` error caused by `pandas` 0.15.0 and fixed in `pandas` 0.15.1

Comment: Added my versions of  ```matplotlib``` and ```pandas``` to question.

Answer (score 2):

Error occurred because data was given that exceeded the number range handled by DateFormatter.

Please refer to the [official reference](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.date2num).

For example, the actual data for the first time series looks like this

```
s.index[0].value
1615797000000000000
```

This needs to be converted to numbers that can be handled by matplotlib.

```
s.index = mdates.date2num(s.index)
s
18701.354167   -65.926651
18701.354225   -42.115551
18701.354282   -24.699627
18701.354340   -12.010081
18701.354398    -2.781321
dtype: float64
```

*update(I am on 3.6.3, so I am fixing it.)*

```
ax = s.plot(style='o-')
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
format_str = '%H:%M:%S'
format_ = mdates.DateFormatter(format_str)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(format_)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't quite understand.  matplotlib appears to handle s.index fine when there's a fractional second component.   When there's a fractional second, the plot also has the timestamps on a 45 deg angle (which is want I wanted)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error message and I used this to resolve it.

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
ts = mdates.epoch2num(ts)
```

After that, I didn't have any error.  I hope it will be help you.

Comment: To be clear, how do I use this solution if I have a pandas series I wish to plot?