# plt.plot not plotting on correct x axis points

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

My code:

```
plt.figure(figsdize = (20,10))
# plot close price, short-term and long-term moving averages 
df['close'].plot(color = 'k', label= 'Close Price') 
df['sma_20'].plot(color = 'b',label = '20-day SMA') 
df['ema_10'].plot(color = 'g', label = '50-day SMA')
# plot 'buy' signals
plt.plot(df[df['positions'] == 1].index, 
         df['sma_20'][df['positions'] == 1], 
         '^', markersize = 15, color = 'g', label = 'buy')
# plot 'sell' signals
plt.plot(df[df['positions'] == -1].index, 
         df['sma_20'][df['positions'] == -1], 
         'v', markersize = 15, color = 'r', label = 'sell')
plt.ylabel('Price in Rupees', fontsize = 15 )
plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize = 15 )
plt.title('ULTRACEMCO', fontsize = 20)
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v69aE.png)

Markers should correlate with the correct date and price but they are only staying on the left side of the x-axis. I'm not sure if there is something going on with the df on why it won't spread across the x-axis.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotting datetimeindex on x-axis with matplotlib creates wrong ticks in pandas 0.15 in contrast to 0.14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26526230/plotting-datetimeindex-on-x-axis-with-matplotlib-creates-wrong-ticks-in-pandas-0) Unlike `df.plot()`, `plt.plot` needs the to_datetime conversion.

Comment: That being said, I cannot reproduce your issue so far. plt.plot with df.index as x axis is plotted with the correct axis and overlaps with similar plot using df.plot. You may need to display versions used and definitely need to post input sample.

Comment: Sorry this is my first time posting here and not the most articulate. I essentially copied this article: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/algorithmic-trading-in-python but only took the code to plot the markers for buy/sell entry points but the markers just stay on one side of the graph. I will try the above suggestion later tonight. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you the to_datetime conversion was needed as the index was an object dtype. I used df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index) when loading the csv file. Also in the future i will be more specific and give a sample to complete the minimal reproducible example.

Comment: OK, so this was indeed a duplicate of the post in my first comment. Glad it helped.